# Typescript: Working with Other JavaScript Libraries with a single function

Tags: interface, module, typescript

In typescript, I understand [how to specify the shape of an external library](http://www.typescriptlang.org/Handbook#modules-working-with-other-javascript-libraries).  Consider though the case in which only a single function from the library is needed or the library is only a single (possibly overloaded) function (such as [this library for the function merge](https://www.npmjs.com/package/merge)).  Having to call the function using the module name -dot- function name is rather verbose:

In file `merge.d.ts`:

```
declare module "merge" {
    export function merge(o: Object, ...args: Object[]): Object;
    export function merge(isDeep: boolean, o: Object, ...args: Object[]): Object
}
```

In some test file:

```
///<reference path="merge.d.ts"/>
import merge = require('merge');
merge.merge({x: 1}, {y: 2});
```

Is there a different way to do this that can effectively replace `merge.merge` with just `merge` on line 3 while still doing checking types?

Comment: Actually, this code doesn't even work.  Even though it type-checks at complie time, at runtime, `merge.merge` is undefined.  I think the issue is that the `merge` npm is only a function and not a module.

Answer (score 1):

Use `export =`. Here is the complete example:

```
declare module "merge" {

    interface Merge {
        merge(o: Object, ...args: Object[]): Object;
        merge(isDeep: boolean, o: Object, ...args: Object[]): Object;
    }
    var merge:Merge;
    export = Merge;
}
```

Comment: I get a compile error on the second occurrence of `declare`: "'declare' modifier not allowed for code already in an ambient context."  Deleting it removes the compile error, but then the symbol `merge` cannot be found in the importing file.

Answer (score 1):

ES6 destructuring will extract the specific function for you:

```
import { merge } from 'merge';
merge({x: 1}, {y: 2});
```

You don't have to change the module structure.

More examples here: http://www.2ality.com/2014/09/es6-modules-final.html